# How to make a tuple based on some derived types?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

For example, I have types

```
template<unsigned i> struct Element;

template struct Element<0> {typedef int Type};
template struct Element<1> {typedef float Type};
template struct Element<2> {typedef double Type};

static const int COUNT = 3;
```

and want to make a tuple of type as

```
std::tuple<Element<0>::Type, Element<1>::Type, Element<2>::Type>
```

How to do it if the COUNT is constant but not always 3?

Comment: What C++ version are you using?

Comment: MSVC 2012 v110, but I can also use v120_CTP_Nov2012.

Comment: With a pack, like `unsigned...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways, which differ in the idea only: [Indices](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices) (when you have (functional) variadic templates available), or manually building the tuple as you go along (when you have Visual C++).

Indices:

```
template<unsigned... Is> struct seq{};
template<unsigned I, unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<I-1, I-1, Is...>{};
template<unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...>{ using type = seq<Is...>; };

template<unsigned N, template<unsigned> class TT,
  class Seq = typename gen_seq<N>::type>
struct tuple_over{};

template<unsigned N, template<unsigned> class TT, unsigned... Is>
struct tuple_over<N, TT, seq<Is...>>{
  using type = std::tuple<typename TT<Is>::type...>;
};
```

Manual recursion:

```
template<unsigned N, template<unsigned> class TT, class TupleAcc = std::tuple<>>
struct tuple_over{
  using tt_type = typename TT<N-1>::type;
  // since we're going from high to low index,
  // prepend the new type, so the order is correct
  using cat_type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<std::tuple<tt_type>>(), std::declval<TupleAcc>()));
  using type = typename tuple_over<N-1, TT, cat_type>::type;
};

template<template<unsigned> class TT, class Tuple>
struct tuple_over<0, TT, Tuple>{ using type = Tuple; }
```

Usage is the same for both versions:

```
using result = tuple_over<COUNT, Element>::type;
```

[Live example for indices.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=53e9b545c30623bcfbb5d49647eb73e6-9a9914b3e2b7ed07c206d6accecccdb6)
[Live example for manual recursion.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b7af0fac75efae61ff6dc0a9773d526b-9a9914b3e2b7ed07c206d6accecccdb6)

Comment: Note that the manual-recursion version works on VS2012 as soon as you replace the `using`-aliases with `typedef`s.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible approach. Given your class template definition:

```
template<unsigned i> struct Element;

template<> struct Element<0> { typedef int type; };
template<> struct Element<1> { typedef float type; };
template<> struct Element<2> { typedef double type; };
```

You could exploit the usual indices framework to write something like this:

```
#include <tuple>

namespace detail
{
    template<int... Is>
    struct seq { };

    template<int N, int... Is>
    struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

    template<int... Is>
    struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> { };

    template<template<unsigned int> class TT, int... Is>
    std::tuple<typename TT<Is>::type...> make_tuple_over(seq<Is...>);
}

template<template<unsigned int> class TT, int N>
using MakeTupleOver = 
    decltype(detail::make_tuple_over<TT>(detail::gen_seq<N>()));
```

And this is how you would use it in your program:

```
#include <type_traits> // For std::is_same

int main()
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            MakeTupleOver<Element, 3>, 
            std::tuple<int, float, double>
        >::value, "!");
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8bd319005f8a6a10269ae2da78130766-9a9914b3e2b7ed07c206d6accecccdb6).